# How to import USGS SDTS ddf file into Qgis

Tags: qgis

I have downloaded SDTS dem files from the USGS.  These extract from tar.gz files as ddf files.
I have tried importing these files into Qgis using "add raster layer and choosing .ddf or .DDF from the file type list.  But the program returns "Unsupported Data Source: C:\tmp\RockyHills_dem\1694744.DEM.SDTS\9948CEL0.DDF is not a supported raster data source".

Can anyone help?